# Redirect same url adding params in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect

I'm trying a redirect on a page that goes like this:

original URL: "http://www.foo.com/products/"

js to redirect:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.foo.com/dept/' + product_var + '/s?template=products/details&layoutVariation=centerbar';
```

*product_var = is the name of the product stored in a variable.

It is working fine on FF and Chrome, but on IE it the original url loads and it never goes to 
the new one.

Is it beacuse of the params? Any suggestion?

Tried to use document.location, but it didn't work either.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: It is a variablethat calls the name of the product on my page. Sorry, forgot to clarify there.

Comment: Seems to work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/DM4m6/1/ - something else is going on in your code. Are you sure a script error isn't preventing it from executing or that code path is ever reached?

Comment: Are you sure you're not having any errors earlier in the script?  Everything here looks ok, but it's possible you have a script error popping up that's preventing this code from running.  Which version of IE are you running?  Have you tried checking the console in developer tools? (F12)

Comment: No errors catched.
version: IE8.
Debugging in developer tools showed no problem either.

Comment: Rencetly i tried window.location.replace and .search. Both didn't work as well... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. :)

The code has this huge declaration of products, image, text, etcs organized this way:

```
content: function () {
       Content = {
            'product-01': {
                'flash': 'swf file',
                'tabs': {
                    0: {
                        'img': 'image',
                        'paragraphs': {
                            0: {
                                'headline': 'h.',
                                'text': 'lorem lorem',
                                'modal': {
                                    'headline': 'lorem lorem.',
                                    'img': 'image',
                                    'text': 'lorem'
                                }
                            },
                           1: {
                                'headline': 'h.',
                                'text': 'lorem lorem',
                                'modal': {
                                    'headline': 'lorem lorem.',
                                    'img': 'image',
                                    'text': 'lorem'
                                }
                            },
                           2: {
                                'headline': 'h.',
                                'text': 'lorem lorem',
                                'modal': {
                                    'headline': 'lorem lorem.',
                                    'img': 'image',
                                    'text': 'lorem'
                                }
                            },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    1: {
                        'img': 'image',
                        'paragraphs': {
                            0: {
                                'headline': 'h.',
                                'text': 'lorem lorem',
                                'modal': {
                                    'headline': 'lorem lorem.',
                                    'img': 'image',
                                    'text': 'lorem'
                                }
                            },
                           1: {
                                'headline': 'h.',
                                'text': 'lorem lorem',
                                'modal': {
                                    'headline': 'lorem lorem.',
                                    'img': 'image',
                                    'text': 'lorem'
                                }
                            },
                           2: {
                                'headline': 'h.',
                                'text': 'lorem lorem',
                                'modal': {
                                    'headline': 'lorem lorem.',
                                    'img': 'image',
                                    'text': 'lorem'
                                }
                            },
                            }
                        }
                    }, // and so it goes
```

Turns out the problem was just a COMMA at the end of one of these declarations. IE just didn't want to continue the script and redirect. Weird thing is, it haven't showed any error...

Thanks all you guys and remember: one missing or extra comma can lead to a huge amount of waste of dev time. Always take a good look at your codes. ;)

Cheers!